# What weapon class is the fastest for a smiter?

Tags: diablo-ii

If I wanted to hit the fastest possible frames per smite (6 frames), which weapon class will allow me to do so?

This is on the ladder.

Comment: Ladder or non-ladder?

Comment: If you're smiting, isn't this dependent on your shield, not your weapon?

Comment: @StrixVaria actually smiting speed is dependent on the weapon, not the shield, which is kind of weird.  The damage is shield dependent, however.

Comment: Strange. Smite Paladin was one of the builds I never really touched.

Comment: @yx. Crushing Blow outweighs Increased Attack Speed for a Smiter.

Comment: @Krazer not for pvp purposes

Comment: @Krazer In my experience, for ubering (the main pvm smiter purpose), hitting a good IAS breakpoint is generally more important than CB, since refilling your life frequently by landing some damage is very important, but as long as you have some CB, you'll eventually kill the ubers.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock This is true, but with (enough) Fanaticism, more CB would outweigh more IAS, because 99% of your damage will be from CBs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Phase Blade with 4x Shael 2x Ber (for Crushing Blow) will allow you to hit max speed WITHOUT Fanaticism, it frees up an aura, so you can use something like Salvation on Uber Mephisto...

For PvP, a Phase Blade with the [Grief Runeword](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Grief) would probably be the best. You can get up to 40% IAS and 400 extra damage. Best of all... it's Indestructible! Think of all the gold you'd save on repairs.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this calculator](http://diablo2.ingame.de/tips/calcs/weaponspeed.php?lang=english) you should be able to reach 6 frames per attack with Smite using any weapon class, given sufficient attack speed boosts from Fanaticism and item bonuses.  I tried using the Falchion (which is a 20 weapon speed, the slowest) and it still showed an IAS level that gave 6 frames per attack.

You can find the weapon speeds for all weapon types at [this page](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/weaponsandarmor.shtml).  As an example, the Falchion requires level 20 Fanaticism and 109% IAS to reach 6 frames.  A Phase Blade (which is a -30 weapon speed, the fastest) can do it with just 65% IAS and no Fanaticism.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, if I wanted the minimum IAS boosting and fanat levels to hit the 6 frames per second, which weapon has the highest weapon speed that will allow me to do that?